# Representing NaN and Inf value with big.Rat in GO

Tags: go, avro

I am using Avro library from [here](https://github.com/linkedin/goavro).

One of the schema fields of Avro looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Col_1", "type":["null",{"type":"bytes", "logicalType":"decimal","precision":20,"scale":5}]}
```

There can be `NaN` and `Inf` values that can come in as input. Since this type is expecting `NaN` value to be of type`*big.Rat`(because of `bytes` type) but `NaN` is of type `float64`, how can I convert `float64` `NaN` to `*big.Rat`?